# Fallback traversal method when no value is found in Node

Tags: neo4j

I'm quite new to Neo4J, so pardon if my question looks silly, but I'm wondering if it is possible to do a fallback match if no value (null) is found in my original query.
This is how the graph looks like:

```
User1 - linked -> Channel 1 

User1 - linked -> Channel 2

Channel1 - has -> property1_channel_1, null , property3_channel_1

Channel2 - has -> property1_channel_2, property2_channel_2, property3_channel_2
```

In this example I'd expect this response to be returned when I query for data User1, Channel1:

*property1_channel_1, property2_channel_2, property3_channel_1*

Is that possible?

Edit:

[image]

How can I structure my query so that if a property - let's say quantity, in one of my products is missing to get its default value from the same product in BASE. Is that possible? In the example the trousers in the BASE is complete entity, but the trousers in the EN channel is incomplete.

Comment: Are all `User`s connected to a "BASE" (which is presumably a `Channel`)? And how does one determine which node is a "BASE"?

Comment: Yes, all users are connected to a BASE Channel, but they may have other channels too. When I query products from Channel X the data object will be merged with the base channel object (by id)  and only the missing attributes will be appended. I know that I can do this programatically, but I was hoping to get this out of the box from neo4j.

Comment: When you make a query, do you will supply the `id` value of these 3 things: a `User`, a Channel, and a "BASE" `Channel`?

Comment: my query will look like this:

match (u: User)-[:HAS_CHANNEL]->(c:Channel)-[:HAS_PRODUCT]->(p:Product)
where u.name="Mladen"
return collect(properties(p))

Comment: Your question says you "query for data User1, Channel1", but your actual query does specify a particular `Channel` (nor a `BASE` Channel). What exactly are you trying to do, and also how would a query know which `Channel` to use as the "BASE"?

Comment: I didn't get your first sentence. The base is always a "BASE" .. the query which I pasted doesn't include the BASE becuase that's where I'm struggling and hence my question - to map results from channel X to results from channel BASE...

Comment: Is a "BASE" node supposed to be identified by a query via a special label, a special property value, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like this

```
// get all the channels the user is linked to
MATCH (u:User)-[:LINK]->(c:Channel) 
WHERE u.name='User1'

// put them in the right order
WITH c ORDER BY c.name

// merge the property maps using apoc.map.mergeList()
RETURN apoc.map.mergeList(COLLECT(properties(c)) AS properties
```

Comment: I think in my case coalesce should do a better job as according to the documentation this should return the first "non-nullable" value in my graph, but still I'm wondering how I can enforce to look to my BASE and extract the respective value from there. 

P.S: I attached a diagram with some explanation.

Comment: Hm.. so I ran your code and I'm getting back only one element in my map 
{
  "name": "...",
  "id": 2,
  "qty": 10
}

Isn't that suppose to spit out 4 different element in it?

Comment: This is the query I executed: 

``` 
match (u: User)-[:HAS_CHANNEL]->(c:Channel)-[:HAS_PRODUCT]->(p:Product)
where u.name="Mladen"
return apoc.map.mergeList(collect(properties(p)))

```